# Edit ImageView in StringRequest nothing updated

Tags: android, android-volley

Good day for all i want to check if the user liked post or not, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343737/inner-class-with-global-variable/36343967#36343967) the solution not work correctly .

I think to write the new solution using **AsyncTask** class but also not work correctly .
Thanks so much, everyone.

```
class Check extends AsyncTask<String , Void , Void > {
    private ImageView e;
    Check(ImageView e)
    {
        this.e=e;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        int id =Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.start();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("yes"))
                {
                    e.setImageResource(R.mipmap.love_post);
                    e.setTag(R.mipmap.love_post);
                } else {
                    e.setImageResource(R.mipmap.empty_heart);
                    e.setTag(R.mipmap.empty_heart);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error ");
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: How ever you are calling volley StringRequest so no need of AsynTask volley will handle threading and onResponce() is UI Thread so you update your UI related things here and remove AsynTask.

Use this to set resource to imageview e.setImageDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.love_post));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AsyncTask`, code in `doInBackground` method runs on workerThread, which is not UI Thread.

It is **superfluous** to using a `volley requests queue` in `AsyncTask` for volley will automatically range its requests to worker thread in background.

Codes suggested like this:

```
// 1.init volley request queue
// 2.construct a request
// 3.add the request to volley request queue
```

If you wanna change UI conpoments, you have two way:

One way is using a `handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            // do something change ui
        }
    }
};
```

In you `onResponse` method of `StringRequest`:

```
Message message = Message.obtain();
message.what = 1; // define a integer to stand for some situation
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

Another way, calling `runOnUiThread()' in you`onResponse`method of`StringRequest`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // change ui
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much to explain your idea ,,, it's work with me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI view inside doInBackground() method. doInBackground() runs on worker thread not on UI thread. Try updating your view inside onPostExecute() method like below,

```
class Check extends AsyncTask<String , Void , Void > {
    private ImageView e;
    Check(ImageView e){this.e=e;}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int id =Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
    String responseText = "";
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.start();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
        responseText = response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error ");
            }
        });
        return responseText;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    if (response.equals("yes")){
                    e.setImageResource(R.mipmap.love_post);
                    e.setTag(R.mipmap.love_post);
                } else {
                    e.setImageResource(R.mipmap.empty_heart);
                    e.setTag(R.mipmap.empty_heart);
                }
     }
}
```